# Why is Python's requests 10x faster than C's libcurl?

Tags: python, c, curl, https, libcurl

Python's `requests` library seems to be ~10x faster than C's [`libcurl`](https://curl.se/libcurl/) (the C API, the CLI application, and the Python API) for a 1.6 MB request (`requests` takes **800ms**, while `curl`/`libcurl` sometimes takes as much as **7 seconds**).

- Why is this?
- How can I get `curl` in C to run as fast as `requests` in Python?

`libcurl` seems to be getting its replies in 16KB chunks, while requests seems to get the whole thing at once, but I'm not sure this is it... I tried `curl_easy_setopt(curl_get, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 1<<19)` but it only seems good to get the buffer size to be *smaller*.

I've tried looking at the [source code](https://github.com/psf/requests/tree/master/requests) for `requests`, and I *think* it uses `urllib3` as its HTTP "backend"... but using `urllib3` directly results in the same (disappointing) results as using `curl`.

Here are some examples.

```
/*
gcc-8 test.c -o test -lcurl  &&  t ./test
*/
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(){
  CURLcode curl_st;
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  CURL* curl_get = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_get, CURLOPT_URL,           "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_get, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 1<<19);
  curl_st=curl_easy_perform(curl_get);  if(curl_st!=CURLE_OK) printf("\x1b[91mFAIL  \x1b[37m%s\x1b[0m\n", curl_easy_strerror(curl_st));

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl_get);
  curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

```
'''FAST'''
import requests
reply = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo')
print(reply.text)
```

```
'''SLOW'''
import urllib3
pool = urllib3.PoolManager()  # conn = pool.connection_from_url('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo')
reply = pool.request('GET', 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo')
print(reply.data)
print(len(reply.data))
```

```
'''SLOW!'''
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo') as response:
  html = response.read()
```

```
'''SLOW!'''
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO
buf  = BytesIO()
curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(curl.URL, 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo')
curl.setopt(curl.WRITEDATA, buf)
curl.perform()
curl.close()
body = buf.getvalue()  # Body is a byte string. We have to know the encoding in order to print it to a text file such as standard output.
print(body.decode('iso-8859-1'))
```

```
curl https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo
```

Comment: It would be useful to know how you are benchmarking these examples so we can compare results. For me, libcurl runs quickest by about an order of magnitude faster than `requests`, which is about how I would expect. So maybe include some detail how you run the examples and time them?

Comment: I just run them from shell with the `time` command`

Comment: Well the fast Python script is very fast because it ends up with a syntax error. And without the `requests` module imported.

Comment: Yes, well I assume that the syntax error is just in the example not in the actual script the OP is running, but still you could be right!

Comment: Perhaps you're using libcurl without enabling [gzip encoding](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html). Sending uncompressed files over HTTP can take significantly longer.

Comment: I can confirm @r3mainer point. Without `CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING` the C program is indeed much slower than the (**fixed!**) Python script. Adding `CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING` will make the C program faster than the Python script.

Comment: @r3mainer That did the trick. Thanks! Now curl runs in 500-700 ms.

Comment: @r3mainer: you should add that as an answer...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way of speeding up the transfer of web content is to use [HTTP compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression). This works by compressing data on the fly before it is sent between the server and client so it takes less time to transmit.

Although [HTTP compression is supported by libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html), it is disabled by default:. From the `CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING` documentation:

> ***Set CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING to NULL to explicitly disable it***, which
> makes libcurl not send an Accept-Encoding: header and not decompress
> received contents automatically.

The default value of this parameter is NULL, so unless you specifically enable HTTP compression, you won't get it.